# Xcode static UITableView cells are blank in the storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

**THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN RESOLVED,
CHECK OUT THE RESOLUTION AT THE BOTTOM OF THIS QUESTION IN "UPDATE #5"**

I built a rather big form for my iPad application. Up until recently, I did not have any issues. However, for no valid reason (at least, none that I could think of), a big part of my table is blank. The elements are still there, they can be seen in the `Document Outline` pane.

When I run the application in the simulator and on my iPad, everything shows up. However, I need to modify the contents of the table (adding and editing cells) but I cannot now.

Here's what I see in Xcode:

[image]

[image]

The elements are clearly there, but I cannot access them.

When running the app, this is the screen I get:

[image]

I am working with a team on this, using Github to sync our code.

I have a small feeling that it might have something to do with a corrupt Xcode installation, but I would really like your opinion on this one.

I am running <s>Xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b)</s> `Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68)`.

Thank you for your help.

**Update #1**
Forgot to mention I'm running OSX El Capitan 10.11.1 on a Macbook Pro mid-2014.

**Update #2**
I should let you know I started this project on Xcode 6 and it worked well with Xcode 7. Could this be an issue going from Xcode 7 to 7.1?

**Update #3**
I finally opened a bug with Apple concerning this situation. Their response was that the bug was fixed in Xcode 7.3 beta 1. I replied that it wasn't fixed, and they ended the conversation by claiming this was a duplicate of another bug. I would only hope that they fix this in 7.3, it's really getting annoying having to cycle through Xcode versions.

**Update #4**
Apple released the latest beta of Xcode 7.3. In the release notes, they say `"UITableViewCell objects that extend below the bounds of a UITableView now draw correctly when scrolled. (23242098)"`. So let's see if this is the case. I will update accordingly.

**Update #5**
I just tested out the latest Xcode 7.3 beta, and the bug has **FINALLY** been fixed! Thanks to anyone who helped in this matter, truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested out the latest Xcode 7.3 beta, and the bug has FINALLY been fixed! Thanks to anyone who helped in this matter, truly appreciated!

Hopefully it stays this way.

Comment: I tried beta, Testing on xCode 7.3 beta 3 (7D141l) but issue is still there in my case.

Comment: Go get the latest version of Xcode 7.2. They actually fixed the issue! I'll update my answer later today.

Comment: xCode 7.2 has fixed. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is it working with an older version of XCode ?
Have you tried to clean your project (Cmd + k) ?
There are recent updates for Xcode 7.1, maybe try to do it.. (or 7.2)

Comment: I will try Xcode 7.2. My teammate ran the project on his Macbook Pro, with Xcode 7.1 and it works on his machine. I really am at a loss here. But I will let you know how Xcode 7.2 goes.

Answer (score 0):

My temporal solution :
In your storyboard

1. open the left panel component
2. Pick the last section and put it
   on the top
3. close Xcode
4. now you can edit
5. reverse the
   process

:X

Comment: So I gave your method a try. Let's just say it did not work as expected. I mean, yes, I saw the missing elements, but they were distorted. The row heights were completely out of whack.

Answer (score 0):

xCode 7.2 has fixed the issue.